# setBackgroundDrawable error on some devices

Tags: java, android

I'm using this code

```
    getActivity().getActionBar()
    .setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.barlist));
```

because of api problem some devices is not support how i'm going to change to setBackground something like this

```
getActivity().getActionBar()
        .setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.barlist));
```

this cause me this error

```
The method setBackground(Drawable) is undefined for the type ActionBar.
```

Comment: In which devices you are facing the problem? Are they Android version specific? Please elaborate.

Comment: samsung tablet 10.1 android version 3.1

Comment: Sure there is no method setBackground in the ActionBar class. You have to follow what @geet has suggested.

Comment: I used getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.barlist)); no error but the image not display.

Comment: Cant tell you what's wrong with this much info. Maybe you could take your project to github and share it, if it isn't private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Action Bar was introduced in Android 3.0. So some device which run on below version that will not support it.
To support Action Bar in lower version u can use Support Libraries. **OR** you can set minimum sdk target in manifest to `11`.

1. Use Open Source [Action Bar Sherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) library which supports from Android version 1.6
2. You can use [Action Bar Compat](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html) library which supports from Android version 2.1

Comment: i changed the sdk target also the same. I'll try use the library that you suggest

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, Action bar API is only added in Android 3.0 (API level 11).
In order to use action bar in lower versions we have to use support library.
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html - this documentation will help you to styling the action bar by defining a child theme of 'android:style/Theme.Holo.Light' and customize it as your requirement.

Comment: i'm quite new in android. Unable to merge this in my code. Thanks in between

Answer (score 0):

There are some methods that are not available from some certain api levels. While some are available. In order to prevent such kind of issues, it is always good or appropriate to read the documentation when using the methods. Even while using eclipse for example, they would mention is that method was from api level 1 (again an example) or api level 11. Based on that, get the sdk int version and inside an if condition use the methods that you wish to use.

Answer (score 0):

In place of that just use this line

```
refreshImg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.refresh_icon);
```

And refer this [VIEW](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource%28int%29)

Comment: What is `refreshImg` and what from where this `refresh_icon` cam from?

Comment: `refresh_icon`  means  your drawable image like this `barlist` and `refreshImg` that is we can implement imageview in place of that you can implement what ever we want like textview,imageview,..........